# Repeat a script (function) for each minute in R

Tags: r, loops, time

I have a long script that calculates several values for a given minute, merges the results with a spatial frame and exports plots as images. Simplified, the data (Df) are in the form:

| Hour | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 02:00:00 | 4 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 03:00:00 | 8 | 6 |

Currently, I select a date by

```
dfdate<-as.data.frame(Df %>%filter((Hour) == (Hour_Input)))
```

and run calculations with several scripts running in the background e.g.:

```
source ("multiply") 
val <-(dfdate$x) * (dfdate$y) 
val 
[8]
```

The structure of the whole code looks similar to this:

```
Hour_Input<-'2022-02-01 02:00:00' #Select Date
Source ("Weight.R") # weight by something
Source ("Merge.R") #Merge with spatial frame 
Source ("Plot.R") #Create Plots in ggplot and export.
```

I would like to repeat the calculations specified in the source files for each minute. What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lacks of efficiency but if you need just a sample of data you could run for a couple hours a `for()` loop and putting into it `Sys.sleep(60)`